# getting the list of images from firebase storage in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I am trying to get the list of images from my Firebase storage but it's not working. So I tried to console log the list of images but I am getting the "Error: [Error: [storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.]"

The code:

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

 const storageRef = storage().ref('gs://wallpaper-(the remaining path).com/leftImg');
    storageRef.listAll().then((result) => {
        console.log('Items:', result.items);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

My storage:
[image]

Comment: It's giving error because in reference you only need to pass only path not including bucket url. If you want to specify bucket url then you should pass in storage function argument

Comment: even after trying your way i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

It's giving error because in reference you only need to pass only folder or specific file path not including bucket url. If you want to specify bucket url then you should pass in storage function argument.

Note- If you don't specify bucket url it automatically picks default bucket but you can also specify bucket url by passing in storage function.
**So replace your line by the line below where you specify your storage reference -**

```js
const storageRef = storage('gs://wallpaper-(the remaining path).com').ref('leftImg');
```

Comment: even after trying your way i am getting the same error

Comment: If you have single bucket only, can you just make storage function argument empty and keep ref function argument as it is?

Comment: One more thing, are you sure you are passing correct bucket in storage function argument rather than mock url?

Comment: i just have one default bucket and even after keeping the storage bracket empty i am still getting the same error

Comment: Did you take a look at my above two comments?

Comment: yes I did and I even tried it while keeping the storage and empty storage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253649/discussion-between-gulshan-aggarwal-and-gaju-masare).